# IIS app now requires physical path credentials

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an application developed using ASP.NET Web API deployed to a site in IIS. Recently the application began crashing during initialization due to an exception saying that it could not access a particular folder (where it writes logs to). The app pool being used by the site uses a domain account and I verified that that account has full permissions on the folder, just as it always has. What wound up fixing the problem for me was to specify the username and password of a user who has access to the folder in the site's Physical Path Credentials field. Previously this had been set to "Application user (pass-through authentication)".

What could have changed in the application or IIS configuration to suddenly require this field to be set?

Comment: Is 'load user profile' on the application pool set to true?

Comment: Yes it is. I have another machine where the old configuration is still working and it looks like it's set to false there.

Comment: It could be that the user profile for your user does not exist on the server you're running it on. This in combination with 'load user profile' true might cause this problem.

Comment: My user is part of the same domain as the app pool user's, I've logged in to the machine as my user, and I've configured the folder explicitly to give my user permissions to it (even though I'm a member of groups that already have access), so I don't think that's it. Switching 'load user profile' to false didn't help, but it also didn't break anything when I respecified the physical path credentials.

Comment: One last try for me: Did you turn it off and on again?

Comment: Did a full server restart, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this came down to a permissions issue. Write permissions on the folder for IIS_IUSRS got changed from Allow to Deny. After switching that back to Allow, I can remove the Physical Path Credentials setting.